# (On EC2 only) error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, maven, amazon-ec2, deployment, dependencies

I have a Java Spring Boot program that run well on my local IntelliJ.
However, when I deployed it to Amazon EC2 (OS: Linux) and compiled my java file by javac myfile.java,

it shows the following errors:

```
java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

java:5: error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
                                             ^
java:6: error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
                                             ^
java:7: error: package org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config does not exist
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
                                                         ^
java:8: error: package org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
```

I have checked my pom.xml and made sure that the following dependencies are added to my project.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In addition, I found my project is using java 17. So I tried to install java 17 on my EC2 as well.
I also tried to set my project java version to 11 and so as my EC2.
Same errors still appeared.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

It seems like the libraries are not added successfully on my EC2 project.
Is there any possible solutions to this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is about Maven build.
Check your maven and try to clean cache.

- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-clear-cache